# Obtener valor de result en UROMessage

Tags: delphi

Me encuentro trabajando con Delphi XE7, con una aplicación que es cliente - servidor, utilizando RemObjects, tengo la necesidad de obtener el result de cada método remoto que realizó y son al rededor de unos 3000 lo cual me resulta complicado modificar uno a uno para obtener su result, revisando veo que el valor del result es guardado en una variable de tipo UROMessage en el Intf, en la cual su método READ permite leer los valores pero siempre y cuando se envíe el nombre del parámetro que en este caso no en todos es el mismo, por lo que quisiera saber si saben de alguna manera de leer el UROMessage sin necesidad de mandar el nombre del parámetro.

Nota: Ya probé guardando el UROMessage en una variable de tipo TStringStream pero me devuelve una cadena al parecer encriptada que no me deja obtener el valor del resultado de la función.

También vi otra propiedad que es el RODLReader pero está aún no logró probarla, si tuvieran algún ejemplo se los agradecería

Comment: Supongo que el tipo correcto es `TROMessage`, sería muy extraño que un nombre de tipo comience con U y no con T (¿quizás la unidad dónde está el tipo?). Viendo la documentación de RemObjects, veo que esta es una clase abstracta y que hay clases como `TROJSONMessage`, `TROSOAPMessage`, etc. Creo que sería de ayuda saber qué tipo de respuesta recibes del servidor, pues eso puede ayudar.  Por otro lado, cuando dices que ya probaste guardarlo en un StringStream, por favor muestra el código que usaste.

Comment: Si el tipo correcto es TROMessage, disculpa coloque el nombre de la unidad, del servidor estoy obteniendo el TROMessage de tipo mtRequest, para guardarlo en un StringStream realice lo siguiente: respuesta:= TStringStream.Create; aMessage.WriteToStream(respuesta); en donde aMessage es mi variable que contiene el result del método remoto

Comment: ¿Qué tiene en la propiedad ClassName ese aMessage? Por otro lado me llama la atención que afirmas que es un _request_, pero buscas en él una respuesta. Quizás sea solo como te expresas, pero me parece que la respuesta estaría en un mensaje mtResponse, y no en un mtRequest.

Comment: ES TROMessage, y por otro lado si tienes razón es un mtRequest

Comment: No puede ser TROMessage directamente, pues esta es una clase abstracta. Tiene que ser uno de sus descendientes, que mencioné en mi primer comentario.